# How would I go about making an alias which runs a command with an ampersand &?

Tags: bash, vim, ubuntu-unity

I'm trying to run gvim work with Unity but I can't seem to get it working.

A workaround is I can run the command `gvim -f MYARGS&` to make it play nice with Unity.

This lets unity manage the menu bar or something. To do this I tried a command like: `alias gvim=gvim& -f`, but that didn't work. Then I tried making it a function

```
alias gvim=gvim_hack
# Why isnt this passing all args (if any) to gvim and running it the way I want?
gvim_hack()
{
  gvim -f $@ &
}
```

but that seems to not work as well. I'm pretty new to linux.

SOLVED: I had a name conflict

```
alias gvim=gvim_hack
gvim_hack()
{
  /usr/bin/gvim -f $@ &
}
```

Comment: Try quoting your expansion: `"$@"`

Comment: When you end a command with `&`, you are sending it to its own process, rather than making it "hog" your current shell. Why can't you use your "workaround"? It might help to expand the question a little bit "I want to type `xxx` and I want the result to be `yyy` but instead I am getting `zzz`. Here are some of the things I tried..."

Answer (score 2):

Use quotes when you define the alias.

```
alias gvim='gvim -f &'
```